# Vue 3 changing the length of both arrays have same values intially

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue 3 where is i am receiving an array of associate schedule from server. Now i am saving this schedule to 2 arrays. I am doing this because i need the original fetched data later after doings changes in associate list array which is my first array.

1. associateList
2. orignalList

The problem is when I am replacing the associate array after doing changes with original array .No nothing works infact original list contains same changes which i did on associate list array even i have not  touched the original list anywhere in my code just saving the data from response on it. I just want the original res on original list array so i can replace associate list with original array when watch function detect changes in attendance list array.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import ApprovalService from "../../service/ApprovalService";
import Toaster from "../../helpers/Toaster";
import moment from "moment";
import { camelCase } from "lodash";
import {
  ScheduleList,
  AttendanceList,
  ApprovedList,
} from "../hoursApproval/IHoursAppoval";
import VueCal from "vue-cal";
import "vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css";
import AssociatePinVerification from "../../components/AssociatePinVerification.vue";

@Options({
  components: { VueCal, AssociatePinVerification },
  watch: {
    attendanceList() {
      const oL = this.orignalList;

      alert('orgi'+oL.length);

      this.associateList = this.orignalList;
      this.checkScheduleContainsLogedHrs();
    },
  },
})
export default class HoursApproval extends Vue {
  private ApprovalTxn;
  private scheduleID = "";
  private toast;
  private orignalList: ScheduleList[] = [];
  private associateList: ScheduleList[] = [];
  private approvedList: ScheduleList[] = [];
  private attendanceList: AttendanceList[] = [];
  private approveManually = {
    hours: 0,
    freezed: false,
    shiftDate: "",
    counterId: 0,
  };

  //DEFAULT METHOD OF TYPE SCRIPT
  //CALLING WHENEVER COMPONENT LOADS
  created() {
    this.ApprovalTxn = new ApprovalService();
    this.toast = new Toaster();
  }

  mounted() {
    this.getSchedule();
  }


  getSchedule() {

    this.ApprovalTxn.getAssociateShifts(this.searchDate).then((res) => {
      const d = this.camelizeKeys(res);
      const s = d.employeeList.scheduleList;
      if (s != null)
      {
        this.orignalList = this.camelizeKeys(d.employeeList.scheduleList);
        this.associateList = this.camelizeKeys(d.employeeList.scheduleList);
      }
      else
      {
        this.associateList = [];
        this.orignalList = [];
      }


      this.scheduleID = d.employeeList.id;
      this.weekStartingDate = d.postStartingDate;
      this.weekEndingDate = d.postEndingDate;
      this.weekNo = d.weekNo;
    });
  }

  camelizeKeys = (obj) => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map((v) => this.camelizeKeys(v));
    } else if (obj !== null && obj.constructor === Object) {
      return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
        (result, key) => ({
          ...result,
          [camelCase(key)]: this.camelizeKeys(obj[key]),
        }),
        {}
      );
    }
    return obj;
  };

  formatDate(value) {
    if (value) {

      return moment(String(value)).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    }
  }

  updateAssociateLogin() {
    if (
      this.loginDetails.loginTime == "" ||
      this.loginDetails.logoutTime == "" ||
      this.loginDetails.loginDate == ""
    ) {
      this.toast.showWarning(
        "Please set date login and logout timings for associate to proceed"
      );
    } else {
      this.associateList = [];
      this.ApprovalTxn.updateAssociateLogin(
        this.loginDetails.loginTime,
        this.loginDetails.attendenceID,
        this.managerApproved,
        this.loginDetails.logoutTime,
        this.loginDetails.loginDate,
        this.weekStartingDate,
        this.weekEndingDate
      ).then((res) => {
        this.toast.handleResponse(res);
         alert(this.orignalList.length);
      //  this.associateList = this.orignalList;
        const d = this.camelizeKeys(res);
        //DOING THIS TO CHNAGE THE RE ACTIVITY OF VUE
        //this.modifyTimings();
        this.attendanceList = d.data;
        //alert(this.orignalList.length);
        //console.log(this.associateList);
       
      });
      this.loginHoursDialog = false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, When you are copying the `originalList` into `associateList`, it's passing the refernce of originalList to associateList and thus any changes made to `associateList` will also be reflected in the `originalList`. You should use something like `this.associateList = this.originalList.slice()`. So to get new refernce to the `assiciateList`

Comment: ok Great let me check Thanks anyways